# SQL Replace Function not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing the below SQL query to replace the double space. But it is giving error. Can anyone help?

Here's the code:-

```
Select *
From (
  select nvcFormName,iEvalID,iFormID,dtCreationTime,dtEvaluatedStartTime,
         fltGradScore,nvcFormattedName,iEvaluatorUserID,
         iAgentUserID,flScore,iQuestionID,nvcQuestionAnswer
  from dbo.vwEvaluationQuestions 
    inner join dbo.vwUser on iUserId = iAgentUserID where iFormID = 160
) as s
Pivot (min(nvcQuestionAnswer) for iQuestionID in ([23732], replace([23742],'  ','') ) as pvt
where dtEvaluatedStartTime > '2017-04-01' and  dtEvaluatedStartTime < '2017-04-30'
order by dtEvaluatedStartTime asc
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I think replace([23742],'  ','') is part of your problem. You are trying to replace a double space in the string [23742] which does not contain any spaces. I think you need to replace that hard-coded value with the column you want to replace spaces in...

Comment: @Neil Hibbert I think [23742] is his column name

Comment: I think without the actual error, we can't give a meaningful answer.

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  Query to replace spaces (ascii x'2020') with single space works in query, but when I execute from wtihin a user defined function, it fails.

WHILE ( at sign HTMLText like '%  %') 
  BEGIN
    set at sign HTMLText = REPLACE(at sign HTMLText, '  ', ' ')
  END

Colletion is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
at sign HTMLText is varchar(MAX)
source column from DB is vachar(maxx), collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

Replace function is used for string character replacement. Use this Instead. Single quotes will do

REPLACE('[  23742]' , ' ', '')

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT nvcFormName
        ,iEvalID
        ,iFormID
        ,dtCreationTime
        ,dtEvaluatedStartTime
        ,fltGradScore
        ,nvcFormattedName
        ,iEvaluatorUserID
        ,iAgentUserID
        ,flScore
        ,iQuestionID
        ,nvcQuestionAnswer
    FROM dbo.vwEvaluationQuestions
    INNER JOIN dbo.vwUser
        ON iUserId = iAgentUserID
    WHERE iFormID = 160
    ) AS s
Pivot(min(nvcQuestionAnswer) FOR iQuestionID IN (
            [23732]
            ,replace('[23742]', '  ', '')
            ) AS pvt WHERE dtEvaluatedStartTime > '2017-04-01'
        AND dtEvaluatedStartTime < '2017-04-30' ORDER BY dtEvaluatedStartTime)
```